# How to place two canvases on top of one another?

Tags: html, canvas

I found similar topics but they all used absolute positioning which placed the canvases at the top left of the page. I have them contained within a div but I'm not sure exactly how to get them to layer properly. I tried using absolute and relative positioning in CSS but I wasn't having any luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this:

```
<style>
    #container { position: relative; }
    .canvas { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
</style>

<div id="container">
    <canvas class="canvas" id="canvas1"></canvas>
    <canvas class="canvas" id="canvas2"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI - above won't work. to make it work you have to do:
<canvas class="canvas" id="canvas1" ></canvas>

Comment: Yup, you're right, of course. I thought any element could be self-closing at the time.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to add `position: relative` to the containing `div` in order to position the canvas elements absolutely within it.