# How to show both canvases when overlaying them?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I followed the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270142/how-to-place-two-canvases-on-top-of-one-another/11270179#11270179) post and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/zbTzq/) fiddle but I am confused as to how to make the lower canvas visible. In my website only the contents of the upper canvas are being drawn.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I'm not sure what it is. On the fiddle page there doesn't seem to be anything special going on and both canvases are drawn just fine.

Here's the CSS and relevant JS from my code:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#drawingCanvas {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

   **JAVASCRIPT**:
previewContext.strokeStyle = "#000";
previewContext.beginPath();
previewContext.moveTo(5, 5); // just testing
previewContext.lineTo(50, 50); // testing
previewContext.stroke();
```

The line is drawn on the lower layer canvas and is not visible. I know this because if I put them side by side I can see the line drawn.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to make the top canvas background "transparent". You might need to post a fiddle with your exact approach, though, if this doesn't answer your question.

```
#drawCanvas {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/zbTzq/4/

Comment: The obvious fix has already been proposed. So the actual problem code needs to be reviewed, as it could be something you're not anticipating.

Comment: Okay, I figured out what was messing it up. When clearing the top canvas the bottom canvas is also cleared. Is there any way to preserve the bottom canvas while clearing the top one?

Comment: Without seeing how you're doing it, I can only guess.