# How to place tree or more canvases on top of one another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, canvas, fabricjs

I want three or more canvases overlay properly. I found similar topics ([How to place two canvases on top of one another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270142/how-to-place-two-canvases-on-top-of-one-another)), just can not do it for overlaying all 3 or 4 canvases together. After the 2nd canvas all other canvases renders below the second canvas.

What I want is a canvas for the base layer. A canvas for the color map and a canvas for the information, which i can click on the 3rd canvas and request the object

Code i'm using:

```
<style>
     #wrapper{ position: relative; }
    .canvas { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
        <canvas class="canvas" id="canvast" style="z-index: -2;"></canvas>
        <canvas class="canvas" id="canvast1" style="z-index: 1;"></canvas>
        <canvas class="canvas" id="canvast2" style="z-index: -2;"> </canvas>
</div>
```

Note: fabric.js library canvas code to fill the canvases

```
 canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvast"); //(canvast1 etc.)
 canvas.renderOnAddRemove = false; // faster loading of canvas
 canvas.add(RectangleObject); //adding object
 canvas.renderAll(); //rendering canvas
```

Comment: Please add more jquery code

Comment: You can only have one canvas on top, all others must be underneath.

Comment: @Blindman67 I know that. My canvast1 (with highest z-index) has opacity to 0.5 and other canvast 0.7. Problem is when i render 2 canvases, they render properly on each other, but when i render extra thirth canvas, then he renders below the canvas 1 and 2

Comment: Yes that is to be expected I think but not at all sure what the problem is?. The two canvas with 0.5 and 0.7 opacity will give a total opacity of `0.5 + 0.7 * (1 - 0.5) = 0.85` (porter-Duff compositing) The bottom canvas will be very hard to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know fabric.js, so I don't know how helpful my answer can be.

I made this jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xn78jzg3/4/

You can see layering three is not a Problem, even with most of your code (only thing I changed was the z-index on canvast2 from -2 to 2 and adding some Styling:

```
.canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: #333 solid 2px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

).

So whatever goes wrong with the rendering of your 3rd Canvas, the error might come from fabric.js.

Comment: Thanks, but can you overlay the 3 canvases on the same position. (in your example, the 3 circle same position)

Comment: Yes. the black box is the 3 canvases. Each circle is just to see that the canvas is there. if you put them in the same coordinates, you would just see the circle of the canvas that ist placed on top (canvast2 in this case).